# Subtype of generic type in java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am confusing about the subtype of generic in java. I have a sample below.

```
public class Class2{

    public static <T extends Number> void set(List<T> list){
        List<T> numberList = list;;

    }

    public static <T extends Integer> List<T> get(){
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        return list;
    }
}
//Does this line is the same as the two below line?
Class2.set(Class2.get());

List<? extends Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Number> numberList = intList;
```

My question: what is different between

```
Class2.set(Class2.get());
```

and

```
List<? extends Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Number> numberList = intList;
```

**UPDATE #1:**
change

```
 public static <T> void set(List<T> list)
```

to

```
 public static <T extends Number> void set(List<T> list)
```

**UPDATE #2:**
Look at the image (took from docs.oracle about generic in java)
Link:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/java/generics-wildcardSubtyping.gif

From the image we know that `List<? extends Integer>` is subtype of `List<? extends Number>`. And we can assign a variable of `List<? extends Integer>` for a variable of `List<? extends Number>`.

In my example above, do I really assign a variable of `List<T extends Integer>` for a variable of `List<T extends Number>`? If so, is `List<T extends Number>` is subtype of `List<T extends Integer>`? Can you guy so me how to prove that if it is or not?
P/S: Link post of oracle docs : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Comment: I update my question due to error when typing. :(

Comment: Why are you [confusing](https://confuser.codeplex.com/) here?

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I update my question again!!!

Comment: `List<? extends Integer>` is NOT a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`!

Comment: Why u said so? The docs of oracle say it was subtype, and the compiler of java also agree with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method set in `class2` takes a list where all elements are of type `T` and `T` is `Number` or any sub class of `Number`:

```
public static <T extends Number> void set(List<T> list){
        List<T> numberList = list;

}
```

This will assign the input parameter `list` to `numberList` and both can contain element of only one type which is represented by `T`(`T` needs to be `Number` or subtype of `Number` e.g. `Integer`).

On the other hand method `get` will return a list of element where each element is of type `T` and `<T extends Integer>` means `T` has to be `Integer` or one of the subclass of `Integer`. We need to understand that this `T` is not same as the one defined in method `set` above.

Now the following line:

```
Class2.set(Class2.get());
```

actually initializes `numberList` with elements where each element is of same type `T`. On the other hand we have:

```
List<? extends Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The confusion seems to narrow down between: `List <? extends Integer>` and `List <T extends Number>`. So the difference IMO is:

1. `List <? extends Integer>` means it is a list of "unknown type" which will extend `Integer` and as per the rule **PECS**(Producer Extends Consumer Super) this can produce elements but can not consume elements.
2. `List<T extends Integer>` is a list of type with super class `Integer` and we can read or add the elements into the list.

   On a side note the signature should have been `List <? extends Number>` and not `List <? extends Integer>` as `Integer` is `final` and cannot be sub-classed.

**Using `extends`**

```
List<? extends Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>();  // Number "extends" Number (in context)
List<? extends Number> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Integer extends Number
List<? extends Number> list3 = new ArrayList<Double>();  // Double extends Number
```

**Using `super`**

```
List<? super Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // Integer is a "superclass" of Integer
List<? super Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<Number>();   // Number is a superclass of Integer
List<? super Integer> list6 = new ArrayList<Object>();   // Object is a superclass of Integer
```

**EDIT:**

The method `get` returns a list of elements with type `T` (T can be `Integer` or subtype):

```
List<Integer> list1 = Class2.get();
```

Now for the `set` method all the following will work:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Class2.get();
Class2.set(list1);
List<Number> list2 = new ArrayList<Number>();
Class2.set(list2);
List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Class2.set(list3);
```

As mentioned in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)

> `Integer` is a subtype of `Number` but `List<Integer>` is not subtype
>   of `List<number>`, rather these are not related at all. The common
>   parent of `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>` is `List<?>`.

As I explained above `List<? extends Integer>` will accept `Integer` and `List<?extends Number>` is even more relaxing. The relation between all these is expressed by the [image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/java/generics-wildcardSubtyping.gif).

Comment: `List<T extends Number>` is not valid syntax-

Comment: @newacct: You are right. If we declare a list like: `List<T extends Number> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();` or `List<T> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();` it would have compilation error. It should either be unknown type `List<? extends Number>` or list of known type e.g. `List<Integer>`

Comment: I updated my question, due to error when typing :(.
I ask this questions because i wonder can we have kind of subtyping with generic in java without using wildcard.

Comment: @akhil_mittal: I update my question. :). I understand what you said about extends and super. Thank you for answer me !!!!

Comment: @Nam I hope it will answer your doubts. I will advise you to ask new question rather than keep on editing it :)

Comment: @akhil_mittal
As you see in the doc. They told you `List<? extends Number>` is parent of `List<? extends Integer>`. But I wonder if `List<T extends number>` is parent of `List<T extends Integer>`. Because from my example it seems like i do can assign a variable of `List<Intger>` to a variable of `List<Number>`

Comment: @Nam you cannot assign `List<integer>` to `List<number>` as they are two completely different types. Check link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html where it is specified that `Box<Number>` and `Box<Integer>` has common type `Object`.